# For any positive number $c$, we have $\int_\Omega cf = c \int_\Omega f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a measurable set, and let $f : \Omega \to [0, \infty]$ and $g : \Omega \to [0, \infty]$ be non-negative measurable functions.

> For any positive number $c$, we have $\int_\Omega cf = c \int_\Omega f$.

$\int_\Omega f = \sup\{\int_\Omega s: \text{$s$ is a simple function, which minorizes $f$}\}$. Suppose that $\sup_s\int_\Omega s = \int_\Omega f$. Then, $c\int_\Omega f = c \sup_s \int_\Omega s$. I understand that $c \sup_s \int_\Omega s = \sup_s \int_\Omega cs$, but how do we know that $\sup_s \int_\Omega cs = \int_\Omega cf$?

For any non-negative measurable function, $f$, there exists a sequence of monotone increasing non-negative simple functions $(s_n)$ converging pointwise to $f$. Also, by monotone convergence theorem, 
$\sup_n \int_\Omega cs_n = \int_\Omega c\sup_n s_n = \int_\Omega cf$. However, I am not sure if I am allowed to use this theorem since it comes after my exercise.

Is there another way to show  $\int_\Omega cf = c \int_\Omega f$ without relying on monotone convergence theorem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that the claimed equality is true if $f$ is simple, by a direct computation. We refer to this fact as $(*)$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary and let $s$ be such that  $ s\le f$ and $\int f \le \int s + \epsilon$. Then $cs \le cf$, and $cs$ is simple. Therefore
$$ \int cf \ge \int cs \overset{(*)}= c\int s  \ge c\int f - \epsilon$$
Therefore, by the arbitrariness of $\epsilon>0$, $$\fbox{$\int cf \ge c \int f.$}$$
For the other inequality, again let $\epsilon >0 $. if $s \le cf$ and $\int cf \le \int s + \epsilon$, then $ \frac sc\le f$, and $\frac sc$ is simple. Thus
$$ \int f \ge \int \frac sc \overset{(*)}= \frac1c \int s \ge \frac1c\int cf - \epsilon$$
 Multiplying by $c$, we obtain
$$ c \int f \ge \int cf - c\epsilon $$
and we similarly conclude that 
$$\fbox{$c\int f \ge  \int c f.$}$$
This concludes the proof that $c\int f = \int c f$.